# How do I pass a hash of options to a rails method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, hashmap

Say I have a `hash` of

```
m = {data:{toggle:true}, class:"btn btn-success"}
```

I want to pass this `hash` directly to the `link_to` method. Something like:

```
link_to "click me", m.flatten
```

**or**

```
image_tag "image.png", m.flatten
```

I haven't been able to get this to work in any way that I've tried, and I haven't been able to find anything by searching.

The most I've been able to do is to pass the values manually like:

```
link_to "click me, data: a[:data]
```

That works but I'd like to do this dynamically.

Comment: Just pass the hash as the last method argument.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth This works with more than the `link_to`. Or is this specific to the `link_to`?

Comment: It's not specific to `link_to`. It's a feature of Ruby method calls.

Comment: just leave out the flatten. You want to pass a hash reference for the hash arguments in a method, just pass a hash, you don't need to do anything special. There's no "hashmap" in ruby, it's a Hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply passing the hash will work. Like this:

```
m = {data:{toggle:true}, class:"btn btn-success"}    

link_to 'Click Me', '/alu', m
#=> <a data-toggle="true" class="btn btn-success" href="/alu">Click Me</a>
```